# jQuery contains doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, contains

I have one problem with jquery contains. It work perfect on firefox.

This is my code.

```
$("input[data-height='cm']").blur(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();

    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
        if(!$(this).val().contains("cm")) {
            $(this).val(text + " cm");
        }
    }
});
```

on chrome it give error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).contains is not a function

How can I fix it please help.

Thank you.

Comment: That functions doesn't work that way. You probably want to use something like `indexOf`, `match` or `test`.

Comment: You are trying to use `jQuery contains` method on `JavaScript string`.

Comment: contains method is of jquery plugin or you can call with dom element selector in jquery, you cann't call this on string.
for this you have to use indexOf.

Comment: why cache `text` if you then use `$(this).val()` all over?  you should replace them (apart from the one you set)

Comment: ok I understand but how it works on firefox?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `indexOf` instead of `contains`

```
 if($(this).val().indexOf("cm") == -1) {
    $(this).val(text + " cm");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you save my lot of time

Answer (score 4):

`.contains()` checks to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element hence you should use it with jquery Objects:

Here you can use `indexOf()` function to check the contents of value attribute.

```
if($(this).val().indexOf("cm")>=0) {

}
```

You can refer [.contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `test`:

```
if(!/cm/.test($(this).val())) {
    $(this).val(text + " cm");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method as `contains` in Chrome. Instead, you should better use `indexOf`:

```
// Instead of...
if ($(this).val().contains('cm')) { /* val() contains 'cm' */ }
// ...do this:
if ($(this).val().indexOf != -1) { /* val() contains 'cm' */ }
```

Please note that `indexOf` returns -1 if occurence is not found in string and >= 0 if occurence is found.